# Can't connect to mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, swisscomdev

I created a **mongodb** service and then a **Service Key** to access the database, but I can't connect. Here's the response I got trying with Studio 3T:

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul

SERVER [kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul

SERVER [kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul}}, {address=kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul}}, {address=kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul}}]
```

How am I supposed to connect ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services are not exposed to the internet. The apps can connect after they were bound to the service. If you need to connect to a service from outside (i.e. over the internet), you need to open an ssh tunnel with `cf ssh`. For more details, consult the following guide:
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. 
We are developing a Meteor application (not hosted on swisscom) that needs an url in order to connect to a mongodb server. Is that possible with swisscomdev mongodb service and an ssh tunnel ? Do you know any other mongodb service provider in Switzerland ?

Comment: cf ssh tunnels are not meant to be used like this and probably won't prove to be stable enough. A common pattern is to push an app that consumes the mongodb service and offers and API that is exposed on the internet.

Comment: Hi Sandro, I work on the same team as Quentin. We're not sure building a middleware mongoDB API is a reasonable endeavour for our small team at the moment. A couple questions:

1. Are you planning to allow the services to be exposed to the internet in the future? What is your reasoning for not doing so? 
2. Is there an open-source API to handle these requests, like you mention? Or does everyone have to build their own?
3. If there's no easy way out of this, do you know another provider that does offer mongoDB with direct exposure to the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: The only other solution I can recommend is to push your code as an app, rather than host it elsewhere.

Comment: @SandroMathys That's what we ended up doing. Thanks for your help.